# How to select controller namespace with Zend Framework 2 routing?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have this as part of my DI config, from the skeleton applicaiton:

```
                'routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
```

I would like to make the following routings:

```
http://me.com/mycontroller/myaction --> 
controller=Applicaiton\Controller\Mycontroller 
method=myactionAction
```

However, the above config produces:

```
http://me.com/mycontroller/myaction --> 
controller=Mycontroller 
method=myactionAction
```

As you can see, the namespace for the controller is missing. Where/how do I put the namespace in? (I know I could make a DI alias for every controller, but that would deafeat the purpose of having segment matching.)

Comment: Segment matching is possible for actions and other parameters, but not for controllers. You might use aliases to help `mycontroller` match `MyNamespace\Mycontroller`, but it is not recommended. The best, easiest and with the most performance way is to have routes for every controller, use segments for actions if necessary.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. If you write your answer below, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use segments for controllers in your routes. Segment matching is possible for actions and other parameters, but not for controllers. You might use aliases to help mycontroller match MyNamespace\Mycontroller, but it is not recommended. The best, easiest and with the most performance way is to have routes for every controller, use segments for actions if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible to achieve what you were originally trying to achieve. In your defaults, you could have added a __NAMESPACE__ key and slightly altered the controller key.

You could have done this:

```
'default' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
            'controller' => 'Index',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

The only other change that would be needed is when you register your controller as an invokable in your module configuration you would have to do it like so:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
```

Take note to how I used Index in the key instead of IndexController.

This __NAMESPACE__ key of the defaults definition of a route and the removing of "Controller" at the end of the key in the invokables array behavior isn't mentioned anywhere in the documentation that I could find. I actually gleaned this information from how the routing of the ZendSkeletionApplication works:

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/2ce1cf0dd40046024970d87d3998e16cde41c7db/module/Application/config/module.config.php